# How to convert numbers to roman numerals using Clojure?

Tags: clojure, roman-numerals

I'm new to Clojure and have a problem with my code. I'm trying make a number converter. This is my code:

```
(defn romanos [numero]
  (when (and (< numero 40) (>= numero 10)) (print "X") (romanos (- numero 10)))
  (when (= numero 9) (print "IX") (romanos (- numero 9)))
  (when (>= numero 5)  (print "V") (romanos (- numero 5)))
  (when (= numero 4) (print "IV") (romanos (- numero 4)))
  (when (and (<= numero 3) (> numero 0)) (print "I") (romanos (- numero 1)))
  (when (= numero 0) (print )))
```

Comment: Hi Francisco, I have edited your question, changed the title and tags. Please take a look at it. Questions should have descriptive titles. Instead of "problem with...", "how to do..." etc. Given the time we can see where the problem is. But many people may just take a quick look and decide to not give the time. So I would suggest editing your question to clarify what exactly isn't happening that should be happening. Easiest way to clarify is to document a few calls, their output and the expected output. You don't have to do any of that. But if you do you will get better answers. Welcome to SO.

Comment: `(< 9 numero 40)` and `(and (< numero 40) (>= numero 10))` are the same thing.

Comment: `(when expr body)` and `(if expr body nil)` are the same thing.

Comment: You might want to consider `recur` instead of self calling. The former doesn't consume stack, the latter can result in a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: It would be more functional if you return a value instead of `print`ing. Try `(str "IV" (romanos (- numero 4)))` for instance. (No `recur`)

Comment: muhuk, is there any reason he (or anyone) should write `(if expr body nil)` instead of `(when expr body)`? Your other comments are all true, but that one just seems like bad advice.

Comment: You are right, `(if _ _ nil)` should be converted to `when`. It was not a suggestion. The first sentence of this comment is a suggestion.

Answer (score 10):

I realize this is likely to be an exercise, in which case this wouldn't be the answer you were looking for, but…

```
(clojure.pprint/cl-format nil "~@r" 123)
;= "CXXIII"
```

To print to standard output instead of returning a string, replace the `nil` with `true`; pass in a `java.io.Writer` instance to print to an arbitrary stream.

See the section on [Formatted Output](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/22_c.htm) of the Common Lisp HyperSpec for further details.

Answer (score 3):

Each of your `when` statements is running in sequence. 1-8 work fine, but numbers larger than 8 trigger the condition `(>= numero 5)` and create a second recursive call.

Your eventual solution should use [`cond`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cond) instead of `when`.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to keep a map of all the valid roman values to their arab values, subtracting a highest one, less then a number in a loop (adding its roman value to result string):

```
(defn roman [n]
  (let [alphabet (sort-by val > 
                          {\I   1   \V   5   \X   10   \L   50 
                           \C   100 \D   500 \M   1000 "IV" 4
                           "IX" 9   "XL" 40  "XC" 90   "CD" 400 
                           "CM" 900})]
    (loop [res "" n n]
      (if (zero? n) res
        (let [[rom arab] (some #(when (<= (val %) n) %) alphabet)]
          (recur (str res rom) (- n arab)))))))
```

Comment: Thx to all my program is running now :3